# jQuery Select2 plugin dropdown not responding to mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'n using the select2 jQuery plugin with an ajax call to retrieve items for the dropdown list as the user types. Multiple selections (tags) are allowed and custom selections are allowed. When the dropdown list appears, if I use the cursor keys to go to the item I want and hit enter or tab, then the everything works fine. The `select2-selecting` callback is triggered and the input gets updated with the selection text.

If I click on an option with the mouse, however, the `select2-selecting` callback is not triggered and the input is not updated. The only thing that happens is that the dropdown menu disappears, nothing else.

I have another select2 input on the same page that allows only one selection and no custom selections. Clicking dropdown items in that works fine. Example on the plugin site similar to what I'm doing respond to clicks too, so it's not a general bug with the plugin.

*I am aware that select2 actually has a hidden, completely translucent container div the size of the screen that is added to the DOM whenever a select2 input has focus. The select2 input sits on top of this 'underlay' and everything else is underneath it. When the select2 input looses focus, the 'underlay' disappears. I thought that the problem might be that the underlay had a higher z-index than the input, so when I click a dropdown item I'm actually just clicking the underlay and causing the input to loose focus. Well, the input (9999) does have a higher z-index than the underlay (9998). I just wanted to rule that out.*

Comment: what version os select2 are you using? can you jsfiddle what you are experiencing?

Comment: I'll give the fiddle a shot (v3.5.1)

Answer (score 0):

This bit of javascript was the culprit:

```
input.on("select2-blur", function() { 
    $(this).select2('close');
});
```

I think that at one stage the dropdown menu was only disappearing if I tabbed out of the input, but if I clicked outside of the input when the dropdown was visible, it stayed there. I had this is as a means to get rid of the dropdown when the input lost focus. It was the cause of the problem though. Strangely, even though I've removed it now, the dropdown disappears appropriately when I click outside the input, but I don't know why that is.